# Custom font for footer in Latex Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, footer

I want my school's name to appear in the centre of the footer, and on the right corner a simple page count. But I want my school's name to appear in its original font. The code below renders everything in **Cabin**, but I want my school's name to appear in **Spectral**. I tried the usual techniques but I seem to be missing something. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[british,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme{infolines}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cabin Regular}
\setsansfont{Spectral}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,nosymbolsc]{newtxsf}
\let\sfdefault\rmdefault

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[School's Name]{}
\subtitle{}
\institute[]{}
\author[]{}
\date[]{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title}
        content...
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `\newfontfamily` macro to define a new family for your school's font and apply it via `\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{family=...}`

(I don't have your special fonts, so I'm using Arial and Times new roman in the example below)

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[british,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usecolortheme{dove}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme{infolines}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\Spectral}{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,nosymbolsc]{newtxsf}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{family=\Spectral}


\title[School's Name]{}
\subtitle{}
\institute[]{}
\author[]{}
\date[]{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title}
        content...
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```